# How to open and close Window 8 Charms Bar from java code?

Tags: java, windows-8

Is it possible to open and close windows 8 charm bar using java program ?
[image]

Comment: take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825164/how-to-disable-the-windows-8-charms-bar-programmatically?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a stab at this:

If you have no problem in simulating key presses in your app, you can do something of the sort:

```
package robot;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyPresser {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         try {
                Robot robot = new Robot();

                // Simulate the charms shortcut: WIN key+C
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```